# CSS layout with centered fixed-width container with two columns; one column fixed width, second column extending to the end of page

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

Here is a screenshot:

[image: The 960 container is transparent, it is colored just for visual purposes]

My only challenge is whether it would be possible to spill the left column out of the container. Is this possible at all? The container will not have a bg, it is only there for visual purposes.

```
#container { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto }
#left-column { ??? }
#right-column { width: 200px; float: right }
```

For more details as to what I'm trying to achieve, here's another screenshot:

[image]

The 960 container is marked by the teal rulers on the sides. The flights have a border at the top and bottom that extend all the way to the left and expands outside of the 960 container.

Comment: Why do you want to get the column out of its container? Why not place it outside the container in HTML? Could you tell us what you are trying to achieve? :)

Comment: I updated the question with another screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="right-column"></div>
    <div id="left-column"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; display:inline-table }
#left-column { height:500px; background:#00ff00;width:auto}
#right-column { width: 150px; float: right;height:500px; background:#00ffff }
```

Check it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/h9XuQ/

Comment: You can remove extra styles

Comment: The #container cannot be 100%;

Comment: Remove display:inline-table property, and give it your desired widht

Comment: The left column is not extending all the way to the left though.

Comment: When you do #container { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;  } the left sidebar will stay within the 960, it needs to extend all the way to the left of the *window* not #container.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h9XuQ/3/ here you go with 960px . i am not sure what you are trying to do. Update this fiddle so i can see what you are trying.

Comment: How can I update the fiddle if what you're asking me to do is the very thing I'm trying to ask how to do? Look at my screenshot and the description.

Answer (score 0):

If you insists putting the left div inside the container, it is impossible without help of javascript.

If what you want is just to take up the remaining section of the page and don't mind where it is placed, you may try the following:

```
#theLeftColumn {
    position：fixed; /*or absolute if it is a direct child of body*/
    margin-top:0px; /*set to other value if you need to leave space for header menu */
    left: 0px;
    /*280px = (width of container)/2 - (width of right fixed width column)
            = 960px/2-200px */
    width: -moz-calc(50% + 280px);
    width: -webkit-calc(50% + 280px);
    width: calc(50% + 280px);
    /*if it is div, the default of display is block, else it is needed to be set */
    display:block;
}
```

Notice that CSS3 is needed for calc function.

Comment: Yes, if you insist on putting it inside a container.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is propably a wrapper element.
The content is obviously placed in a wrapper element which size must larger than 960px.
I guess it's all about the following code,

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="960container">
  <div id="left-column"></div>
  <div id="right-column"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is that what you want to ask?
Not sure whether you want to know the origin or the styling problem.

Comment: The stuff outside the 960container don't really matter. You can pretend that outside the 960container is just the <body>.